# Ionic 4 - convert promise for token to observable?

Tags: angular, rxjs, ionic4

I'm trying to submit a post, and send a token with the header.  However my storage.get returns a promise, and I can't figure out how to get the value of token, out of the storage.get.  I think converting it to an observable might help, but I can't figure out how to do it.

```
  sendPostRequest() {
    var token: string;
    this.storage.get('ACCESS_TOKEN').then((val) => {
      token = val;
    });
    const headers = new HttpHeaders()
    .set('Accept', 'application/json')
    .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
    .set('Authorization',  'Bearer ' + token)
    .set('responseType', 'text');
    let postData = this.signatureForm.value;
    this.httpClient.post("http://localhost:3000/signature", postData, { headers: headers })
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.presentToast();
      }, error => {
          this.showError = true;
          this.errorMessage = error.error.message
    });
  }
```

Comment: If you really want to convert your promise to an observable, you can use the `from()` function of RxJS. But as mention in the answers, you don't really need it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that `storage.get()` is asynchronous, you should be handling the subsequent operations within the `then` block. This will prevent the issue of the `token` being `undefined`, as you will need to wait for the promise from `storage.get()` to be returned.

```
sendPostRequest() {
    var token: string;
    this.storage.get('ACCESS_TOKEN').then((val) => {
      token = val;

      const headers = new HttpHeaders()
        .set('Accept', 'application/json')
        .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
        .set('Authorization',  'Bearer ' + token)
        .set('responseType', 'text');

        let postData = this.signatureForm.value;
        this.httpClient.post("http://localhost:3000/signature", postData, { headers: headers })
          .subscribe(data => {
            this.presentToast();
          }, error => {
            this.showError = true;
            this.errorMessage = error.error.message
          });
    });

  }
```

However, if you want to do it using the Angular/RxJS way, you may convert the promise into an observable using the RxJS [from](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/creation/from.html) operator. Then, the subsequent assignment of token and the returning of the post request can be handle within pipeable operators, such as [switchMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/switchmap.html).

```
from(this.storage.get('ACCESS_TOKEN'))
  .pipe(
     switchMap((val) => {
       token = val;
       // do the rest here
       // return this.httpClient.post()
     }),
   ).subscribe(data => {
     this.presentToast();
   }, error => {
     this.showError = true;
     this.errorMessage = error.error.message;
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to implement de logic inside de success callback of your promise, like this:

```
    sendPostRequest() {
      var token: string;
      this.storage.get('ACCESS_TOKEN').then((val) => {
        this.postSignature(val);
      });
    }

    private postSignature(token: string) {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders()
         .set('Accept', 'application/json')
         .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
         .set('Authorization',  'Bearer ' + token)
         .set('responseType', 'text');
    let postData = this.signatureForm.value;
    this.httpClient.post("http://localhost:3000/signature", postData, { headers: headers })
         .subscribe(data => {
           this.presentToast();
         }, error => {
          this.showError = true;
          this.errorMessage = error.error.message
         });
    }
```

Promise are asynchronous, that means you don't have the token value until finish the request, that's why you need to implement the logic in the success callback.